# ANTLR: Can't chain child rule method calls

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to find the column position of the first character for a certain token while using an ANTLR visitor. Here are my rules (simplified for demonstration):

```
expExpr : PLUS expExprTail ;
expExprTail : EXP expExpr       #expExprTailOpLabel
  | /* epsilon */               #expExprTailEpsLabel
  ;
```

(Note that I'm using labels for the two rules in `expExprTail`)

I want to find the position of the given token **when I'm in the `expExpr` rule** (that's when I've determined an error has occurred). But the token is the first token in the `expExpr` rule accessed via the `expExprTail` rule.

My thought was that (in the visitor) it could be accessed like this:

```
  @Override public void visitExpExpr(LangParser.ExpExprContext ctx) { 
    ExpExprContext expExprContext = ctx.expExprTail().expExpr();
  }
```

However, this code won't compile and ANTLR reports that it can't find the `expExpr()` method on the `ExpExprTailContext` class. How can that be, when `expExpr` is a rule referenced in the `expExprTail` rule?

Answer (score 1):

Given the parser rule `foo`:

```
foo
 : A
 | B
 ;
```

the following method is generated:

```java
T visitFoo(TParser.FooContext ctx)
```

But when adding labelled alternatives to this parser rule:

```
foo
 : A  #altFooA
 | B  #altFooB
 ;
```

the `visitFoo` will not be available anymore (and neither is `TParser.FooContext`!), and will be replaced by the following rules:

```java
T visitAltFooA(TParser.AltFooAContext ctx)

T visitAltFooB(TParser.AltFooBContext ctx)
```

If you want to directly access the `exprExpr` rule like `ctx.expExprTail().expExpr()`, you will have to remove the alt labels:

```
expExpr : PLUS expExprTail ;
expExprTail : EXP expExpr
  | /* epsilon */
  ;
```